# Pagination in AWS php SDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am trying to implement ec2 API in a project. How do we implement pagination on
ec2-descibe-instances. I send the option as null

```
$ec2 = new AmazonEC2($key, $secret);
$ec2->set_region('us-east-1');
$allInstances = $ec2->describe_instances(null);
```

If I have hundreds of instances, rendering all instances might be an issue. So want to lazy load 10 instance at a time. I see python boto having some limits but the php SDK for aws.

Can any one please let me know how we can accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

you should refer to this q [How to get list of EC2 instances with Amazon PHP SDK 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15233913/how-to-get-list-of-ec2-instances-with-amazon-php-sdk-2)

Add Page parameter to the filter as Page=1, page=2 and so on.

```
$result = $ec2Client->DescribeInstances(array(
        'Filters' => array(
                array('Name' => 'instance-type', 'Values' => array('m1.small'),'Page' => 2),
        )
));
```